# How do you resize the title of a webpart on a webpart page in SPF2010

Tags: web-part

Sharepoint Foundation 2010, I want to make the title of the webpart larger than the text inside the list so that it stands out.  How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS for that purpose. Simply create a new CSS rule and bind it to the Web Part title:

.ms-WPTitle { font-size: 1.5em; }

Answer (score 0):

How I ended up doing it was to set the part to have no title, then with a content editor webpart directly above it make it a link and set the text to the size you want.  Kinda hackish, but it works and only effects that one spot.

Comment: I upcoted Waldek's response as that's a preferred general solution for other's viewing this post looking to answer the same question; but your solution would work just fine for single instances.